# Looping through a JSON value and adding it to variable but it stays as null

Tags: php

I have a code which goes through JSON and grabs there `color` value and adds it to a `$color` variable. Next line of code will push add data to the array, but the `color` stays null. I tested with `echo` and the color code comes out, just if I add it to the variable it's null. What could be the issue?

```
        $color = '';
        foreach($descriptions['tags'] as $tag){
            $color = $tag['color']; //Adding it to the variable
        }
        $inventoryItems['items'][] = array(
            'id' => $assets['assetid'],
            'name' => $descriptions['market_hash_name'],
            'price' => $price,
            'icon' => $descriptions['icon_url'],
            'color' => $color //Gives null here
        );
```

Comment: It looks like the last item in `$descriptions['tags']` has `$color = null;`. Regardless it would be helpful if you provided a data sample and an expected output

Comment: Might be useful to see a sample of the JSON

Comment: You also need the `$inventoryItems['items'][] = array( .......` inside the foreach loop otherwise you will only get data for the LAST occurance in your JSON array

Comment: Here is the JSON: http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198172798401/inventory/json/730/2

Answer (score 0):

If you look closer at your data, not all the `[descriptions]` Arrays contain a `[color]` so you are going to have to be more specific in finding the correct occurance.

```
foreach($descriptions['tags'] as $tag){

    if ( isset($tag['color']) ) {
        $inventoryItems['items'][] = array(
                                        'id' => $assets['assetid'],
                                        'name' => $descriptions['market_hash_name'],
                                        'price' => $price,
                                        'icon' => $descriptions['icon_url'],
                                        'color' => $tag['color']
                                    );
    }
}
```

Also beware as some occurances of `[description]` have more than one occurance of `$tag` that contain a `[color]`. Note sure what you would want to do in that situation.